# PHP sessions and session destroy

Tags: php, variables, session, alert, status

I have created a page where 'Job's' stored on a database are deleted.
On a page called

```
delete.php
```

the job to be deleted is selected.
The user is then directed to deleteaction.php where the job is deleted.
The user is then auto redirected back to

```
delete.php
```

This all works fine however once the user is returned to delte.php I would like a pop-up/ alert saying 'Job deleted'.
However if the user enters the page not from

```
deleteaction.php
```

then I dont want this pop-up to appear. I have tried to use sessions where a variable
$status
indicates if the user has just been directed to

```
deleteaction.php
```

and a job has been deleted.

**Code on deleteaction.php:**

```
session_start();

 $id=$_GET['id'];

$sql= "DELETE FROM `Job` WHERE `Job`.`Job_Customer_id`='". $id."';";

 $stmt=$dbh->query($sql);

 $status = "deleted";
$_SESSION['delstat'] = $status;
 header("Location:delete.php");
```

**Code from delete.php:**

```
session_start();

$status = $_SESSION['delstat']; 

if ($status = "deleted"){
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Job Deleted")';
    echo '</script>';
}
else {
    echo "No";
}

session_destroy();
```

........

The problem is the page delete.php always displays the alert that a job has been deleted every time the page is visited.
Not sure if its something wrong with my loop or the session use?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're presently assigning `=` instead of comparing `==` in

```
if ($status = "deleted")
```

being always TRUE

change that to

```
if ($status == "deleted")
```